# Como fazer view pager de imagens como app mercado livre e outros

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Gostaria de pedir ajuda de vocês sobre como fazer este layout que nem do app Mercado Livre e outros por aí, como Viva real Imóveis.
O layout que eu preciso é igual a esta imagem que estou colocando abaixo, Seria uma toolbar do mesmo jeito e logo abaixo um view pager com aquelas bolinhas que passam as imagens e ao clicar nas imagens elas ficam em fullscreen e continuam com bolinhas indicadoras. Abaixo do view pager de imagens eu colocaria todo o resto do meu layout. A parte principal que preciso da ajuda de vocês seria essa mesmo, do slide de imagens com o arrastar dos dedos com contador de bolinhas e fullscreen também. Em material Design.

Poderiam me ajudar?

[image: Slide images]

Comment: A dúvida em si é fazer aquele indicador atrelado ao `ViewPager`?

Comment: @Wakim O indicador e o view pager com efeito de material design junto com a toolbar.

Comment: Hmmm, seria no caso esse [efeito](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/) com o `ViewPager` ao invés do `ImageView`?

Comment: @Wakim seria EXATAMENTE este efeito que colocou no link só que com o ViewPager de Imagens com aquelas bolinhas, mas o efeito é exatamente este, o layout. Gostaria de ajuda com esses efeitos pois sou muito novo no Material Design ainda. Inclusive no meu layout vai ter uma "fab" de "+" atrelado ao viewpager exatamente como no link.

Comment: Esse artigo vai dar uma boa base, mas eu nunca tentei trocar o `ImageView` pelo `ViewPager`, mas acho que pode funcionar... Posso colocar uma resposta com o setup básico. E nesse caso, para o indicador eu recomendo usar o [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) do Jake Wharton.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada na bilbioteca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema com base na resposta e comentários do @Wakim. Sugiro primeiro ler o post dele para depois ver o meu código. O Layout ficou bem parecido na verdade como o "WhatsApp" na tela de perfil de um contato.

Segue abaixo código para ficar com Layout do jeito que eu queria (um pouco diferente do "MercadoLivre")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/pagerIndicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_image_photo_camera"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Cada detalhe neste código é importante, até mesmo a ordem da `Toolbar`, `Padding` do `CirclePageIndicator`, etc.

Obrigado @Wakim pela ajuda.

Créditos:

1. Resposta do @Wakim
2. [Animação da Toolbar com scroll](http://www.antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)
3. [Link indicado pelo @Wakim nos comentários da minha pergunta](http://www.antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Answer (score 4):

Partindo do início, a nova biblioteca do google, `Design Library` trás diversos componentes prontos com algumas interações comuns do Material Design.

Basta incluir a biblioteca como dependência no seu `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

# Outras dependencias implicitas...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
```

Só que ai vem a surpresa... Junto com o `Design Library` vem outras 3 que ela também depende... Se já utilizar elas, não tem problema. Mas pode trazer um overhead ao seu app caso não as utilize.

Além disso, para implementar os indicadores eu recomendo utilizar a `ViewPagerIndicator` do Jake Wharton.

Com isso, tem que ser incluído a dependência também:

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
```

Mas como o JakeWharton não publicou a biblioteca dele como um AAR, você precisa incluir os seguintes repositórios ao seu projeto, após a declaração de plugins:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Seguindo do tutorial do Antonio Leiva sobre o [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/)

Vamos ter o seguinte layout (bem boilerplate :/):

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
            </FrameLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Algumas observações:

- Para que o efeito de scroll funcione, você precisa usar componentes com a função de `Nested Scroll`. Conheço apenas 2: `NestedScrollView` e o `RecyclerView`. Não sei se o `ListView` ou `GridView` funcionam bem sem nenhuma customização.
- Alguns componentes tem alguns "travamentos" durante o Scroll, se isso ocorrer, recomendo a biblioteca [`smooth-app-bar-layout`](https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout) que fornece os mesmos componentes com melhorias no comportamento.

---

Acredito que o setup do `ViewPager` seja conhecido, mas abaixo segue a forma de conectar o `CirclePageIndicator` e o `ViewPager`:

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

pager.setAdapter(...);

CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
circleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
```

---

Edit: Alguns ajustes conforme feedback:

1) Adição do `layout_gravity="bottom"` e `layout_marginBottom="16p"` no `CircleViewIndicator`.

2) Troca do `android:layout_height` do `CollapsingToolbarLayout` para `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Existem boas referências sobre os componentes novos:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html
- https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32

Comment: Estarei testando a implementação e assim que possível, caso seja desta forma, estarei marcando sua resposta como correta.

Comment: desta forma não funcionou corretamente do jeito que eu queria. O indicador do View Pager ficou lá em cima e não no final e meio da foto como e o do Mercado Livre. Outro ponto é que depois que a barra está totalmente encolhida (Feito um scroll para baixo) Ela não fica na cor primária e sim fica com fundo da imagem. E também o ícone de Navigation Home UP (Aquela seta para voltar) também sumiu após colocar as imagens no ViewPager.

Comment: @Wakin. Sim, estou utilizando:  `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`. A seta aparecia antes de eu definir as imagens no ViewPager. Após criar o PagerAdapter e vincular ao ViewPager, ela sumiu. Vou testar as outras coisas que disse. Por que você colocou o ViewPager e o Indicator dentro de um FrameLayout?

Comment: Não cheguei a testar, mas poderia postar uma imagem? Sobre os pontos: 1) Nesse caso é uma questão de `layout:gravity="bottom"` + algum `layout_marginBottom="16dp"` no `CircleIndicator`. 2) Preciso ver uma imagem para saber o problema. 3) Nesse caso, preciso ver, antes ela aparecia? Esta usando o `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUp(true)`?. Vou atualizar a resposta.

Comment: @LucasSantos Coloquei pra dar o efeito de `zIndex`, mantendo o indicator por cima do ViewPager. Acho que tem um bug ali, troquei o `layout_height` do `CollapsingToolbarLayout` para `wrap_content`.

Comment: não funcionou nenhuma das suas edições. Continuou diferente. Vou tentar postar imagens e o código.

Comment: descobri o problema. Está na ordem dos childs da `CollapsingToolbar`. A `Toolbar` tem que vir por último, ou seja, depois do ViewPager, e não antes. Caso não fique depois acontece esse problema de não aparecer o botão de `Up Navigation` e da `Toolbar` não ficar da cor configurada em `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"` em `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Agora só falta uma coisa para mim. O CircleIndicator ficar na posição centralizada e perto do `bottom` do `ViewPager` e a barra de status ficar transparente quando está expandido a `CollapsingToolbar`.